# Errors while trying to access Google Knowledge Graph API on Android

Tags: android, api, freebase

I have been trying to use Google Knowledge Graph API, this seems like one stubborn API due to the fact that I cannot find any tutorials and the only tutorial I found by Google seems to not work at all, I have created an API Key, enabled Google Knowledge API but now I am getting this error

```
` com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
 ﹕ {
 "error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
[
{
"message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
 "domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
],
 "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}`
```

the code I am using

```
 HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search");
        url.put("query", "Taylor Swift");
        url.put("limit", "10");
        url.put("indent", "true");
        url.put("key",API_KEY);
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Here is another thing, when I use the API key directly like this `url.put("key",API_KEY)` it gives me the above error, when I load it from the `values` file like this `url.put("key",R.string.API_KEY)` it gives me this error

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

I have tried everything I know and nothing has helped, with other Google APIs works for me, but with the Graph API it seems, tt will take me weeks to make this thing work.

Comment: Your second question is a distraction. The value of `R.string.API_KEY` is a compile time generated index value to Android resources and NOT your string. For your first part - how are you generating your API KEY. How are you running your test. I sense one or more things missing from the following instructions: https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/how-tos/authorizing#installed-applications like `package name`

Comment: @MorrisonChang so what is the correct way of inserting the api?via resource string or directly placing it there like in the other example? firstly am getting the `sha1 fingerprint` from my machine via terminal in the `google console` am enabling all `APIs` am to use, then navigating to credentials where am creating an `android key`,adding my package name like `com.me.myProject` and my `sha1 fingerprint` and hit the `create` button

Comment: what I have noticed is my `API key` is ok, when I disable the `knowledge graph api` from the google console I get this error message `"Project has not activated the kgsearch.googleapis.com API. Please enable the API for project` so now I do not know what could be the problem, worse is its the code provided by google.

Comment: Any luck? i am facing the same issue! need help

Comment: It is working for me. I am creating a Browser Key instead of Android Key under API Manager - Credentials while creating API KEY. For some strange reason, it is working